# No "Done" button at AVPlayerViewController Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I can't seem to create the "Done" button at my video. I have attached my code below:

```
- (IBAction)playVideoButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"mp4"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    //to view on full UIScreen

    self.mc = controller;
    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [player play];    
}
```

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the running app?

Comment: I cant seem to add in a picture but it is just to add a "Done" button at the top left corner to close the video and go back to the initial screen.

Comment: You can try MPMoviePlayerController instead of AVPlayerViewController.Below link might be useful to you http://freefeast.info/tutorials-for-beginners/iphone-development/play-a-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller/

Answer (score 1):

You were not using the `AVPlayerViewController` class properly. Here is how you are supposed to use it:

```
- (IBAction)playVideoButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"mp4"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

With that, you'll have the "Done" button comes with `AVPlayerViewController` along with other playback buttons (e.g. pause/resume and etc.).

Comment: Ahh yes, I understand why, THANK YOU so much!!

Comment: @user8555346 here is a sample code from Apple if you want to learn more about customizing the layout of the video playback and etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html